# Let $f$ be the sum of distances to vertices. The Fermat point $p_0$ satisfies $ \left.\frac{df}{dt}(p_0+t\vec{u})\right|_{t=0}=0$ for all $\vec{u}$.

Tags: geometry, analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

**Problem:** We consider a triangle $a=\left(x_1, y_1\right), b=\left(x_2, y_2\right)$ and $c=\left(x_3, y_3\right)$ with interior angles strictly less than $2 \pi / 3$. Let $p=(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ with $d_1(x, y)=|\overrightarrow{p a}|, d_2(x, y)=$ $|\overrightarrow{p b}|$ and $d_3(x, y)=|\overrightarrow{p c}|$.

Prove that if $f(x, y)=d_1+d_2+d_3$ has a minimum value at $p_0=\left(x_0, y_0\right)$ then for all $\vec{u} \in \mathbb{R}^2$,we have
$$
\left.
\frac{d f}{d t}\left(p_0+t \vec{u}\right)
\right|_{t=0}=0
$$
and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\left(p_0\right)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\left(p_0\right)=0$. We say that $p_0$ is a Fermat's point of $abc$.

**My solution:** Let $g(t) = f(p_0 + tu)$, $t\in \mathbb{R}$. Since $f$ has attains its minimum value at $p_0(x_0,y_0)$ then $g$ attains its minimum value at $t=0$. By the first order necessary condition, we have
$$g'(0) = 0 \Leftrightarrow \left.\dfrac{df}{dt}(p_0 + tu)\right|_{t=0} = 0.$$
This is equivalent to
\begin{align*}
&\langle u, \nabla f(p_0)\rangle = 0,\ \forall u \in \mathbb{R}^2\\
\Leftrightarrow\ & \nabla f(p_0) = (0,0)^T.
\end{align*}
Hence, $\dfrac{df}{dx}(p_0) = \dfrac{df}{dy}(p_0) = 0$.

I hope everyone could take a look at my solution and correct it if you are interested.

Comment: You are miswriting this. You need $$\frac d{dt} f(p_0+tu)\Big|_{t=0}.$$